# Are countably infinite unions limits?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cantor-set

I was working with the Cantor Set today and its construction prompted me to think about infinite unions/intersections a little more than usual.

What exactly does an infinite union/intersection represent?

I think of $$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} F_{i}$$ as $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n} F_{i}$$

I understand what is going on at each finite stage, but I'm confused about what is occurring at the "end" of the process.

For example, we define the Cantor set to be the infinite intersection of increasing middle thirds sets, but is the Cantor set itself the "limit set" of this process? And if so what does it mean for a set to be a limit?

I appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i$ is the set defined by the property $$ x\in \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty F_i \iff\mbox{$x\in F_i$ for some $i\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$}.$$

The thing that separates the infinite situation from the finite one is that we need to consider a countably infinite collection of sets $\{F_1,F_2,\ldots \}$ instead of only a finite collection $\{F_1,F_2,\ldots, F_n\}.$

So we don't really need to think of a limiting process here... it's more about the "completed" infinity of the collection of $F_i.$ Consider that in theory the $F_i$ might bear no obvious relation to one another, though in practice of course they often do. However, if it's useful, we can imagine building up the union progressively, by adding first the elements of $F_1,$ then all the elements of $F_2$ that weren't already included, then all the elements of $F_3,$ and so on.

Comment: Right, I understand what happens at the finite stages. My issue is when we $define$ a set to be the infinite intersection/union of some collection of sets. Are we considering the defined set to be the limit of the "building up" process in the case of unions?

Comment: @Newman There was nothing about "finite stages" in the definition I gave of $\cup_{i=1}^\infty F_i.$ Something is an element of the union of a collection of sets if and only if it's the element of some member of the collection. Something is an element of the intersection of a collection of sets iff it is an element of each member of the collection. The "infinity" is encapsulated in the existential/universal quantifier.

Comment: I was referring to the intuitive idea of what is going on. Similar to what you mentioned with "building up the union progressively..."

Comment: @Newman Sorry, added a bunch to that last comment in an edit. I don't know if I understand your question.

Comment: I think I'm asking if we can think of these infinite unions/intersections like limit ordinals. Taking the infinite union to be the supremum of the partial unions or something like that.

Comment: @Newman Even though you don't need to, you can certainly think of the union/intersection of a collection indexed by an ordinal as a recursive process where at each stage you add/subtract sets. Also, you can think of the union as the smallest set that each $F_i$ is a subset of, so this is like a supremum. Likewise, the intersection is the largest set that is a subset of each of the $F_i,$ similar to an infimum. (In fact they *are* sup and inf with respect to the $\subseteq$ partial order.)

Answer (score 0):

For *any* set $A$, and *any* collection of sets $\{F_a\}_{a\in A}$ indexed by $A$, the union

$$\bigcup_{a\in A} F_a$$

is defined to be the set

$$\{x\in F_a:\text{for some }a\in A\}.$$

That’s all. We need no notion of limiting behavior, and the cardinality of $A$ doesn’t matter. It just happens to be notation for countable sets that we say

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} F_i$$

which feels similar to

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i$$

but ultimately isn’t defined in the same way.